# Test Condition for Image Loading Error in javaScript

Tags: javascript

**Background:**

I am creating a local browser app on my computer for reading manga (Japanese comic books). I am trying to make the app run almost exactly the same way mangareader.com is set up, except for each manga page, mangareader.com has a different web page. My app uses javascript to navigate pages and chapters.

Right now, I have the code set up so that when I hit the right arrow key, the image on the web page moves to the next page in the chapter. I have variables for both the chapter and the page number that are used for setting the image source. The directory for this app has a new folder for each chapter. When I am on the last page of the chapter and I try to run the function that moves to the next page, the function tries to set the source to an image file that does not exist. For example, if the last page of the chapter is 20.png, the function will try to set the source to 21.png. I use the onError event for the image object to change the chapter number and reset the page number to 1.

**Problem:**

This all works very well until I try to use a similar process to navigate backward. I can move backward within the chapter, but as soon as I'm on page 01.png and I try to navigate backward, I need to find a way for the function to move to the last page of the previous chapter. Each chapter has a different number of pages, so I can't just tell the function to set the page number to 20.png. I need to find a way for my function to give me the page number for the last page of the last chapter. I know that all of this could be easily fixed with a database, or even storing chapter page totals in an array, but I am looking for a way that only uses javascript (no PHP) and that doesn't require me to manually populate an array.

**What I've Tried So Far and Why It Hasn't Worked:**

I set up a test image that is hidden using CSS, display: none. When I try to go back from page 1, a function is triggered that starts setInterval. SetInterval runs a function that increases the page number by one and then resets the source of the hidden image. Pretty much a timed version of the function described in the first paragraph of this question, except its time triggered, not event triggered. Since I want this function to ultimately tell me what the page number of the last page in the folder is, I set the onError event to stop the setInterval and record the last page that loaded properly in a variable. The only problem is that depending on how fast the setInterval is set, it still has a chance to update my test number once or twice before onError can be triggered, so the function might return that the last page is 25 or 26 when its really 24. This is ideally how the function would look:

```
var counter = 1;

function findLastPage()
{
timerId = setInterval("checkPage()",1);
}

function checkPage()
{
counter++;
document.getElementById("testImage").src = chapterNumber + "/" + counter + ".png";
if(document.getElementById.onError == true)
    {
    timerId = clearInterval(timerId);
    lastPage = counter - 1;
    }
}
```

The only reason this doesn't work is that onError is strictly an event and has no boolean value that can be used as a test condition. I've also tried an infinite while loop and having the onError event update the variable that closes the infinite loop, but that method was far worse than the setInterval method.

**What I'm Really Looking For:**

I'm looking for a solution to finding the last page in the chapter. changing the setInterval to ever 1 second instead of every 1 millisecond work, but theoretically, if the computer is running very slowly, this could still be wrong. What I would really like to see is a way that I can create a test condition here. A test condition would allow me to check if the page exists before continuing on with the script. The biggest problem with the setInterval script is that doesn't stop to check if the image exists before continuing on with the script. So if someone could give me a way to create a test condition, it would be awesome. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Javasript also has Arrays. `var arr = [];`

Comment: I know Javascript has arrays, I just don't really want to populate one myself. If I can't find the solution I'm looking for I'll probably have to set the script to populate an array for me, by using my setInterval function...